# VS C# how to reference active control property?

Tags: properties, controls

I have numerous buttons that I'd like to reference their ID or text when clicked.  How do I reference them?  In VBA, it's something like me.ActiveControl.  Is there something like that in Visual Studio C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can always reference control by specifying its ID.

For example: you have one TextBox called `txtBox` and a Button called `btnSubmit`. On OnClick button event you can reference TextBox by `txtBox.Text`[or any other Accessible Parameter]. In the code below `object sender` represents control which raised event (`btnSubmit`)

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Text = "some text";
}
```

Also I'm not familiar with VBA, but both VB.net and C# have property `ActiveControl` - this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) describes how to use it.